# Showing Google Analytics Data in real time

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I would like to show number of visitors on a site since beginning of the month, number of users on the current day and currently on site.

I have Google Analytics installed, I tried to solve this issue with Embed API by enabling Google Analytics API from developer console - but I requires user authorization, etc.

What would be the easiest way to show analytics on-site without user authentication and accepting access by Embeded API, etc. Application is written in Angular, so Javascript API is the one I look for.

Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Authorization has to happen in order to get the data you want. Either you can let visitors to your site authorize themselves, or you'll have to authorize server-side on their behalf.

Once authorized, you can do something similar to what the [Third Party Visualization](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/third-party-visualizations/) Embed API demo shows. It uses a custom `ActiveUsers` Embed API component and includes the source code to show how it works.

Whether you use the `ActiveUsers` component or not, the basic gist is that once the users is authenticated via the Embed API, you have access to the method `gapi.client.analytics.data.realtime.get`, which you can use to query this data.

Here's where that happens in the source code for the `ActiveUsers` component:
https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools/blob/master/src/javascript/embed-api/components/active-users.js#L69-L87

Answer (score 2):

Authentication with the Analytics service is mandatory. But the [OAuth 2.0 Service Accounts (for Server to Server Applications)](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) can be used to automate it in many cases.

It's unclear to me (from a quick scan) if the [Auth options of the Embeed API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/component-reference#auth) would work with the automated authentication scheme, you may want to go through the details.

You *should* be able to use the [Analytics Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) and maybe the [Analytics Real Time Reporting API (beta)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/) which work with the automated authentication according to their guides (look for the `Authorisation` sections on the left frames of the respective guides).

Donno if this qualifies as easy, tho, YMMV :)

Comment: Thank you, Dan. I applied for Real Time Reporting API - hope to get it during 24 hours. 
Everything is hard before it's easy - thank you for direction. Have a nice and easy way today :-).